# newtx seems to require newpx: "cannot open encoding file for reading"

Tags: pdftex, miktex, newtx, newtxmath

A specific MikTeX installation shows the following error for a document that includes `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ntx-ecth-tlf.enc): cannot open encoding file for 
reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

A Google search for `ntx-ecth-tlf.enc` finds the [file listing of the `newpx` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newpx/enc?lang=en) (!) as first entry. Are `newtx` and `newpx` related to each other? Will installing the `newpx` package help? Shouldn't this dependency be captured by MikTeX then?

Comment: The issue of November 2020 seems that there are files missing in MikTeX: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/663

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the `newpx` package seems to have helped. Both packages are by the same author, but there seems to be no reference to `newpx` in the `newtx` package. This probably qualifies as a bug report, will investigate.

**UPDATE**: According to Michael Sharpe, the package author, this is an unwanted dependency which should be corrected soon.

**UPDATE²**: It has become available [on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx?lang=en) rather soon, and a while later also [in MikTeX](http://miktex.org/packages/newtx).

Answer (score 1):

There is a reference in `newtx` to `newpx`, it is in `newtx.map`:

```
ntx-Italic-tlf-th-t1 ntxtmri " encntx-ecth-tlf ReEncodeFont " <[ntx-ecth-tlf.enc <ntxtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-osf-th-t1 ntxtmri " encntx-ecth-osf ReEncodeFont " <[ntx-ecth-osf.enc <ntxtmri.pfb
```